# Ejabberd configuration for virtual host

Tags: ejabberd

How to create a new virtual host in Ejabberd 16.06 through terminal without restarting Ejabberd ?

If I am modifying in Ejabberd.yml its requires restart.I don't require that, Because its in production environment and I don't need any down time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. The ability to add/delete virtual hosts is only added in 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option called reload_config but I cannot handle these changes. If you don't want to restart ejd you may:

- want/try to upgrade to latest 17.x stable version (as mentioned above 17.04 is the first with this feature)
- add another machine (phys/virtual) to the cluster, shutdown ejd service, do some mods and restart it